# Массив внешних ключей

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

У меня есть таблица `users`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    user_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    first_name text NOT NULL,
    last_name text NOT NULL,
    company text,
    profession text,
    description text,
    
    CONSTRAINT PK_users_user_id PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
);
```

А еще есть таблица `teams`. По идеи, в `teams` должно быть поле `members`, которое было бы FOREIGN KEY, ссылающееся на `users`. Я пробую создать этот массив так, но ничего не получается:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams (
    team_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    company text,
    description text,
    members integer[] ELEMENT REFERENCES users,
    
    CONSTRAINT PK_teams_team_id PRIMARY KEY(team_id),
);
```

Как организовать `members`. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Это не поддерживается. Можно только вынести эту связь в отдельную таблицу.

Comment: Если игрок может быть строго в одной команде, то связь Many-to-one. Если игрок может быть более чем в одной команде, то связь Many-to-many. Почитайте про то как они реализуются. Это стандартная тема.

Comment: Спасибо всем, я понял